# PowerShell DSC Invalid MOF definition for node 'localhost'

Tags: powershell, dsc

As I'm new to PowerShell and also DSC (and programming in total) i have a question to which i couldn't find an answer in the web.

I'm trying to install an msi (or an exe) with PS DSC. I sucessfully wrote a script to check and install windows-features and to install JDK and set the ressources. 
But with my next step I seem to be overchallenged.

so heres my code so far:

```
$ConfigurationData = @{
AllNodes = @(
            @{
                NodeName="*"
                PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword=$true
             }
       )
    }



    Configuration AppFabric
    {
        param (
            $TargetNodes,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [PSCredential]$Credential
        )

        Import-DscResource –ModuleName ’PSDesiredStateConfiguration’

        Node localhost
        {

            Package AppFabric
            {
                 Ensure = "Present"
                 Name = "AppFabric"
                 Path  = "$PWD\src\AppFabric\package\appfabric-1.1-for-windows-server-64.msi"
                 ProductId = ""
                 LogPath = "$PWD\logs\$env:computername-AppFabric"
                 Arguments = "/i HostingServices,CacheClient,HostingServicesAdmin"
                 Credential = "$Credential"
            }
         }
      }

      AppFabric -OutputPath $PWD\mof\AppFabric\

      Start-DscConfiguration -Path $PWD\mof\AppFabric\ -wait -verbose -Force
```

So as you see i'm trying to install AppFabric on a Windows Server 2012R2 up to date.

When i Run the script i get following error:

[image]

I have no clue, what that means and can't find anything on the web that could help.

If you need further information, let me know, as I said, I'm new to this :x

Thanks!

Edit: 
If I try to do it without credentials I get the following:

```
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the **Credential** property as a string instead of **PSCredential**.
Remove double quotes from **Credential** property to fix the issue.

```
Package AppFabric
            {
                 Ensure = "Present"
                 Name = "AppFabric"
                 Path  = "$PWD\src\AppFabric\package\appfabric-1.1-for-windows-server-64.msi"
                 ProductId = ""
                 LogPath = "$PWD\logs\$env:computername-AppFabric"
                 Arguments = "/i HostingServices,CacheClient,HostingServicesAdmin"
                 Credential = $Credential
            }
```

Comment: Yep, that was dumb. Thank you. I think it partly solved my problem, but I'm not quiet sure where this is going. I hoped i could skip all the credential-process, as it wasn't neccessary in the previous installations, but if I do it without it the script stops at
"VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'."